# Material Design Select Dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, material-design

I'm trying to create different Form elements that reflect Google's material design principles. I have noticed that I'm not really able to find a  dropdown example anywhere. The closest that I could find was in the [Polymer Project](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-dropdown-menu) .

**My questions are:**

1. Is Google shying away from using this particular form input type with Material Design?
2. Could anybody please direct me to how to create a similar Select Form input to the one displayed in the link. I am aware that the one displayed in the link is not a form input per se, but surely something similar is possible for a form `<select>`.

I have tried transforming a normal select using CSS but this seems to be extremely tricky. The other option is to recreate the select using Javascript and Unordered lists, but how user (Device and Developer) friendly is this solution?

Comment: Why not use the one in the link? Polymer is actually a Google maintained project, so in answer to your first question, no Google is not shying away from it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dropdown {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:30px;
    position: relative;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    border-radius:5px;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:400;
    background:#26A69A;
    color:#FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 6px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.dropdown > input{
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-2;
}
.dropdown > label{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.drop-ttl{
    font-weight:400;
    padding:5px 20px;
}
.dropdown ul {
    width:100%;
    font-weight:400;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type:none;
    background:#FFF;
    color:#26A69A;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 6px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius:5px;
}
.dropdown ul >li{
    padding:5px 20px;
}
.dropdown ul > li > a{
    color:inherit;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.dropdown ul > li:hover{
    background:#DEDEDE;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label > ul {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked />
    <label for="checkbox1">
        <div class="drop-ttl">Dropdown</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a>First</a></li>
            <li>Second</li>
            <li>Third</li>
            <li>Fourth</li>
        </ul>
    </label>
</div>
```

This is a nice css-only material dropdown. +1 if it helps.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my take using a bit of jQuery, `UL` list and a hidden `input` (so you can eventually submit data-value with your form:)

```js
jQuery(function($){
  // /////
  // MAD-SELECT
  var madSelectHover = 0;
  $(".mad-select").each(function() {
    var $input = $(this).find("input"),
        $ul = $(this).find("> ul"),
        $ulDrop =  $ul.clone().addClass("mad-select-drop");
    $(this)
      .append('<i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>', $ulDrop)
      .on({
      hover : function() { madSelectHover ^= 1; },
      click : function() { $ulDrop.toggleClass("show"); }
    });
    // PRESELECT
    $ul.add($ulDrop).find("li[data-value='"+ $input.val() +"']").addClass("selected");
    // MAKE SELECTED
    $ulDrop.on("click", "li", function(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $input.val($(this).data("value")); // Update hidden input value
      $ul.find("li").eq($(this).index()).add(this).addClass("selected")
        .siblings("li").removeClass("selected");
    });
    // UPDATE LIST SCROLL POSITION
    $ul.on("click", function() {
      var liTop = $ulDrop.find("li.selected").position().top;
      $ulDrop.scrollTop(liTop + $ulDrop[0].scrollTop);
    });
  });
  // CLOSE ALL OPNED
  $(document).on("mouseup", function(){
    if(!madSelectHover) $(".mad-select-drop").removeClass("show");
  });
});
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 1px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
}

*{box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;}

body{
  font: 16px/24px Roboto, sans-serif;
  background: #fafafa;
}


/*
MAD-SELECT by Roko CB
*/
.mad-select .material-icons{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.mad-select{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  padding-right: 8px;
}
.mad-select ul {
  list-style: none;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0; padding:0;
}
.mad-select li{
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height:24px;
  line-height:24px;
  display: none;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: initial;
}
.mad-select > ul:first-of-type{
   max-width:120px; /* COMMENT FOR AUTO WIDTH */
}
.mad-select > ul:first-of-type li.selected{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 24px);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.mad-select i.material-icons{
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
/*jQ*/
.mad-select ul.mad-select-drop{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  visibility: hidden; opacity:0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.24s;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.mad-select ul.mad-select-drop.show{
  visibility: visible; opacity: 1;
  max-height: 160px; /* COMMENT IF YOU DON?T NEED MAX HEIGHT */
}
.mad-select ul.mad-select-drop li{
  display: block;
  transition: background 0.24s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mad-select ul.mad-select-drop li.selected{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
}
.mad-select ul.mad-select-drop li:hover{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,400,300,100&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

Select an option:
<div class="mad-select">
  <ul>
    <li data-value="1">Option 1</li>
    <li data-value="2 foo">Option 2</li>
    <li data-value="3 bar">Option 3</li>
    <li data-value="4">Option 4</li>
    <li data-value="5">Option long desc 5</li>
    <li data-value="6">Option 6</li>
    <li data-value="7">Option 7</li>
    <li data-value="8">Option 8</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="hidden" name="myOptions" value="3 bar">
</div>
```

Comment: You really drawn a good component. But I don't know why the list seems terrible when there's another component below it. Like if you have two of it one per line you will see what I'm talking. Can you (please) provide some fix to this? =)

Comment: @RhuanKarlus fixed, thanks for noticing. I've also added a fix that closes already opened dropdowns on page click: http://jsbin.com/kogade/4/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 4):

you can get it as [Material-UI component](http://material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu)

if you are using AngularJs, [Material Angular project](https://material.angularjs.org) is a great place for material design ( still, dropdown not available. currently they are working for it as md-dropdown directive)

edit:
it seems you can even use polymer element by importing this:

`<link rel="import" href="components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">`

Comment: You just gave two answers that require frameworks as dependencies to implement

Comment: im using one of these, it made to suggest those :D 
Only after seeying @Vann'Tile Ianito's answer, I realised answer needed to be in pure css!

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue over at github on this; https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/854.

In the meantime I made my own "css only"-version (simple) http://codepen.io/pudgereyem/pen/PqBxQx/

```
  <!-- Standard Select -->
  <div class="mdl-selectfield">
    <label>Standard Select</label>
    <select class="browser-default">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

If you want a Javascript-version that styles the whole thing, I would recommend checking out materializecss.

Answer (score 3):

Look at https://github.com/CreativeIT/getmdl-select. It is our implementation of select component using native mdl-menu styles. It provides a fast way to make select input with native Material design lite menu style.

You can find worked example on this page http://creativeit.github.io/getmdl-select/

Comment: please add some content from the link

Comment: @Vladislava I tried your select. It looks great, works almost great - one problem is, that whatever I select, the value of combobox stays the same. I copy pasted your example from page and it shows always "Belarus" whatever country I select. I also imported 3 files into my project: getmdl-select.min.js, getmdl-select.min.css and gulpfile.js. I assume it should be all...Am I doing something wrong? Do you have some downloadoble example with simple html page + all necessary imports?

Comment: @qkx Don't forget mdl native components, such as material.min.css and material.min.js.
You can download simple example https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6JGsUwJ3Y7bZFcwX1c3b2NFdEE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tronic247 Material](https://material.pages.dev/components/select-menus/) for creating a select menu. See the below example.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>A Basic HTML5 Template</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tronic247/material/dist/css/material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body class="container p-5">


  <div class="select-container filled">
    <label for="demoselect">Select</label>
    <select id="demoselect">
      <option></option>
      <option value="v">Option 1</option>
      <option value="v">Option 2</option>
      <option value="v">Option 3</option>
      <option value="v">Option 4</option>
      <option value="v">Option 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tronic247/material/dist/js/material.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```